# Python, pandas dataframes. pd.fillna() for specific columns with specific values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, na

For example dataframe like this:

```
| 1  6   nan ... |
| 1  nan 5   ... |
|nan 2   4   ... |
|... ... ... ....
```

I want to use values from list `[11, 12, 13 ...]` to fill nan with the values from list. So, 10 for nans from first column, 12 for second etc. 
Is there a way to do this without using `.hstack()` combined with `df[column].fillna(value)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass a `Series` to `DataFrame.fillna`; the columns of the DataFrame are aligned with the index of the `Series`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
nan = np.nan

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,nan],'B':[6,nan,2],'C':[nan,5,4]})
ser = pd.Series([11,12,13], index=list('ABC'))
print(df.fillna(ser))
```

yields

```
      A     B     C
0   1.0   6.0  13.0
1   1.0  12.0   5.0
2  11.0   2.0   4.0
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Solution

```
from itertools import cycle
import pandas as pd

c = cycle([11, 12, 13])

df.applymap(lambda x: next(c) if pd.isnull(x) else x)
```

The cycle function returns an object that you can get next values from.  Then use `applymap` to access each cell of `DataFrame`.  If it's null then fill with the next item in the cycle.